# var dump outputting bool(false)

Tags: php, mysqli, mysql, mysqli-multi-query

Having problems at the moment when inserting into a database im running to different `mysqli` queries to insert into the same table but inserting into different fields when running this the second query that is inserting into `order_contents` selected images is outputting `bool(false)` when running a var dump and won't insert to the database.

I have included my code below so that it can be seen.

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    if($_GET['id']=='logout')
    {
    unset($_SESSION['userdetails']);
    session_destroy();


    }
    require 'instagram.class.php';
    require 'instagram.config.php';

    if (!empty($_SESSION['userdetails'])) {

    $data=$_SESSION['userdetails'];

    // Store user access token
    $instagram->setAccessToken($data);

    } else
    {   
    header('Location: index.php');
    }

    # Set page title and display header section.
    $page_title = 'Checkout' ;
    include ( 'includes/header.html' ) ;

    # Check for passed total and cart.
    if ( isset( $_GET['total'] ) && ( $_GET['total'] > 0 ) && (!empty($_SESSION['cart']) ) )
    {
      # Open database connection.
      require ('connect_db.php');

      # Store buyer and order total in 'orders' database table.
      $q = "INSERT INTO orders ( id, total, order_date ) VALUES (".$data->user->id.",".$_GET['total'].", NOW() ) ";
      $r = mysqli_query ($connection, $q);
           var_dump($q);
      # Retrieve current order number.
      $order_id = mysqli_insert_id($connection) ;

      # Retrieve cart items from 'shop' database table.
      $q = "SELECT * FROM shop WHERE item_id IN (";
      foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $value) { $q .= $id . ','; }
      $q = substr( $q, 0, -1 ) . ') ORDER BY item_id ASC';
      $r = mysqli_query ($connection, $q);

      # Store order contents in 'order_contents' database table.
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
      {
        $query = "INSERT INTO order_contents ( order_id, item_id, quantity, price )
        VALUES ( $order_id, ".$row['item_id'].",".$_SESSION['cart'][$row['item_id']]['quantity'].",".$_SESSION['cart'][$row['item_id']]['price'].")" ;
        $result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
      }

      var_dump($query);

      # Display order number.
      echo "<p>Thanks for your order. Your Order Number Is #".$order_id."</p>";

      # Remove cart items.  
      $_SESSION['cart'] = NULL ;
    }
    # Or display a message.
    else { echo '<p>There are no items in your cart.</p>' ; }

    if (!isset($_SESSION['myvar']) ){

    } else {
      $q = "INSERT INTO order_contents ( selectedimages ) VALUES (".$_SESSION['myvar']['0'].") ";
      $r = mysqli_query ($connection, $q);
        var_dump($q);
          var_dump($r);
            var_dump($query);
        mysqli_close($connection);
      # Close database connection.
    }

    # Create navigation links.
    echo '<p><a href="shop.php">Shop</a> | <a href="forum.php">Forum</a> | <a href="home.php">Home</a> | <a href="goodbye.php">Logout</a></p>' ;

    # Display footer section.
    include ( 'includes/footer.html' ) ;

    ?>
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/22662582/285587

Comment: Also, you are using mysqli wrong way. The only point of using this extension is in using **prepared statements**

Comment: im only a php and mysql newbie at the moment and trying to learn as I go along thanks for the link and help :)

Comment: @YourCommonSense what would be the best way to run this query to do another database insert?

Comment: the best way would be to use http://stackoverflow.com/tags/pdo/info

Comment: by the way, what error did you get?

Comment: In any future projects I have I will try to use this instead.

Comment: error returned as  

Uncaught exception 'mysqli_sql_exception' with message 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '://distilleryimage10.s3.amazonaws.com/f98a40546a9211e38b010e4cd888e04e_8.jpg)' at line 1' in /home/wwwsocia/public_html/checkout.php:71 Stack trace: #0 /home/wwwsocia/public_html/checkout.php(71): mysqli_query(Object(mysqli), 'INSERT INTO ord...') #1 {main} thrown in /home/wwwsocia/public_html/checkout.php on line 71

Comment: There are no "future projects", because you have NO project yet. These random lines of code you banged together is not a "project".

Comment: I know that I've a long way to go as I said I'm only trying to learn at the moment and hope to improve by learning from the error of my ways.

Comment: Exactly. So, there is no point to learn wrong way from start.

Comment: I appreciate your help, I was actually learning this from a book the book must be a bit outdated I'll try and purchase one of the newest versions.

Comment: if this code is from the book - this book is just awful